# Why does parameter order matter for `this`?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, this, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to insert a new node into a BST recursively. I'm not sure why the order of parameters matters in my method. Here's the Node class:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(val, left = null, right = null) {
    this.val = val;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
}
```

Here's the BST class. Insert is a method on the class. Insert inserts the new node and returns the tree.

```js
class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor(root = null) {
    this.root = root;
  }

 insert(val, current = this.root) {
    if (this.root === null) {
      this.root = new Node(val);
      return this;
    }

    if (val < current.val) {
      if (current.left === null) {
        current.left = new Node(val);
        return this;
      }
      return this.insert(val, current.left);

    } else {
      if (current.right === null) {
        current.right = new Node(val);
        return this;
      }
      return this.insert(val, current.right);
    }
  }
}
```

But when I flip the parameters, ie `insert(current = this.root, val)` and `return this.insert(current.left, val)` and `return this.insert(current.right, val)` it doesn't work and instead returns undefined. Why is that the case?

I pass in the parameters in the same order as the function defintion so I don't believe that's the case. I thought that maybe it had to do with hoisting but I don't understand how that could be the case either. My guess is that it maybe has to do with `this`?

Comment: Did you also change the argument order for whatever is initially calling `insert()`?

Comment: -facepalm- that was it. thank you!!

Comment: Hehe, been there, done that.